# SQL Server Delete Trigger is Firing When Transaction Rolled Back

Tags: sql-server

I have a strange situation.  In .NET I am wrapping a number of table inserts in a transaction using TransactionScope.  I have triggers for each of INSERT, DELETE, UPDATE to log history in another table.  As expected, if an exception occurs, the transaction is rolled back and the INSERTs are removed. The strange thing is this is causing the DELETE trigger to run, and I get all of the delete log records in my history table.  Should this be happening and is there a way to avoid it?

Comment: Can you provide minimal setup for reproducing?

Comment: LIke @GiorgiNakeuri said above it is hard to rigure out without code. But I would guess that if you are using a try catch block or some other error checking you aren't breaking out of the statement. IF you are using the try catch block it will rollback and then keep going if you don't escape out of the trigger.